# Chrome table css glitch using border-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a table style defined as follow for selected elements:

```
tr[selected] {
    background: #FFF;
    border-color: #000000;
    color: #000000;
}
```

I apply this style using javascript:

```
$this.unbind().change(function () {
        element = $(this).parents('tr');
        if ($(this).is(':selected')) element.attr('selected', '');
        else element.removeAttr('selected')
    });
$this.checkbox();
```

It works howewer, I get a weird glitch using chrome (not happening with firefox for instance), sometimes, after selecting and unselecting elements, a part of the border-color property is still applied:

Expected:

[image]

Sometime:

[image]

Is that known ?
Is there a workaround for this behavior ?

Comment: can you show a working example on codepen ?

Comment: The code is not enough to reproduce the problem. However, to be compliant with standards, when setting the selected attribute you could use `element.attr('selected', 'selected')`

Answer (score 0):

Set the style for the `tr` rows as a `display: block;`, otherwise table elements may not behave as expected in other type of containers. This is working for me:

```
tr {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
}
tr[selected] {border: solid 1px #000;}
tr:not([selected]) {border: solid 1px #fff;}
```

Comment: I don't really like that. I would prefer to understand why that's happening

Comment: I changed the answer. I think it has to do with the default display mode of table rows.